# Math with full query in Flux

Tags: influxdb, flux

I have some power sensors for devices like fridge or PC in my house and a full sensor that measures the complete house consumption.
What I try to achieve a pie chart with the individual divese-usages for my house. That works great. Only problme is, that I now need to calculate a "rest" or "others" values.
For that I want to take the number from the full sensor and subtract all other values.

I have two individual queries that are giving me the two numbers. I just dont find a way to subtract one from the other.

The queries are as follows:

Full sensor:

```
from(bucket: "hoi2c")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "power_usage")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "total_usage_no_neg")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["type"] == "sh_em3-01")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 100y, fn: sum, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "sum")
```

Sum of all other devices:

```
from(bucket: "hoi2c")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "power_usage" or r["_measurement"] == "devices_power_usage")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "total_usage_no_neg")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["type"] == "sh_plug_wohnwand" or r["type"] == "sh_plug_office2" or r["type"] == "sh_plug_office1" or r["type"] == "sh_plug_kuehlschrank" or r["type"] == "sh_plug_datacenter" or r["type"] == "sh1_plpm_gartenhaus")
  |> group(columns: ["_field"])
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 100y, fn: sum, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "sum")
```

Does anyone has an idea how I can achieve that?

Best Regards
Lasse

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You could save whole result to variable like this:

```
full_sensor = from(bucket: "hoi2c")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "power_usage")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "total_usage_no_neg")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["type"] == "sh_em3-01")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 100y, fn: sum, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "sum")

other = from(bucket: "hoi2c")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "power_usage" or r["_measurement"] == "devices_power_usage")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "total_usage_no_neg")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["type"] == "sh_plug_wohnwand" or r["type"] == "sh_plug_office2" or r["type"] == "sh_plug_office1" or r["type"] == "sh_plug_kuehlschrank" or r["type"] == "sh_plug_datacenter" or r["type"] == "sh1_plpm_gartenhaus")
  |> group(columns: ["_field"])
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 100y, fn: sum, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "sum")

full_sensor - other
```

Comment: Hi Darthbane426 and many thanks for your answer.

when I copy paste this it returns:
"invalid: error @18:1-18:20: stream[A] is not Subtractable"